# GoogleSignInAccount.getId() return different id number for the same user in different devices

Tags: android, google-signin

Im facing with strange behavior with Google Sign-In in Android.
Im using the google user id to identify the user and i'm getting it by calling "GoogleSignInAccount.getId()"
99% of the times it will return the same id on different devices but sometimes i'm getting different id number.
Doe's it make sense? The id should be the identifier for the user, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The id should be the identifier for the user - correct. Please do key user by id and never by email. If an email (account) is deleted and re-claimed, the id will change.

See "important" notice in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people